# copying a war file from jenkins to jetty using sftp

Tags: maven, ssh, jenkins, jetty, sftp

I have a maven project for which I want to move the war file created by jenkins to a remote jetty server using **sftp/ssh** connection.

Could anyone suggest how to do it as I am naive to jetty and jenkins.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Highly recommend googling for articles on setting up SSH. Not being evasive, just pointing out how SSH works is well worth learning. There are a couple of very useful Jenkins plugins for managing items like SSH keys, but you'll struggle to troubleshoot problems if you don't understand the underlying technology. Finally, the plugin you need to push files using SSH is : https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin Very best of luck

Comment: @MarkO'Connor I forgot to mention that I've done some ground work regarding this issue and I already installed the plugin.But I got stuck regarding the private key issues.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a job to Jenkins that executes a certain shell command; so just add a new job with the command you would use to transfer the file manually and set the job to depend on your exiting build job that generates the WAR, so that it runs after the buld automatically (alternatively: configure it as a post-build action on your existing job).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar but the other way around. I wanted to download a folder from a sftp server to my local machine. Ended up writing some python and using pysftp to solve it.

Basically you just use the sftp put function.

```html
sftp.cd('whatever')              # temporarily chdir
sftp.put('/my/local/filename')  # upload file to public/ on remote
```

Perhaphs you will find my code useful (which is doing the reverse that is downloading a folder): http://sebastiannilsson.com/en/blogg/python-for-sftp-and-mysql-backup/